# Can 'domestic animal' mean 'livestock'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Is it correct to use 'domestic animal' instead of 'livestock' (cattle)?

Comment: They're not the same. Cats and dogs are domestic animals, but they are not livestock.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Indeed — English-speaking countries do not normally keep dogs as livestock for food or pelt or whatnot. Even working dogs like for a sled up above the arctic circle wouldn’t get called that.

Comment: Ooh. [A duplicate on ELL.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/can-domestic-animal-be-used-instead-of-livestock)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I noticed that, too (and even answered in both places, wondering if a meta question ought to be asked). Looks like the O.P. is hungry for an answer.

Comment: @MohammadSanei: You really should have included the part about the "Domestic Animal Food Production Company" as part of your question (in either place). When most people first hear the two words, they would say, "No, they're not 'the same'." However, the context you provided in your comment may cause some to change their mind, and realize that, as part of a company name, "domestic animal" might _include_ cattle (but that's still not a word that's _equivalent to_ "cattle").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domestic animal is not "the same" as cattle, but cattle kept and fed by livestock farmers can be considered "domestic."

There's some good info on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_domesticated_animals), and [another web site](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_domestic_animals) says:

> A domesticated animal is any animal that depends on a human for food, water and shelter; this includes farm animals such as cattle, horses, sheep, chickens, goats, dogs and cats.

The state of Florida uses [this definition](http://www.duhaime.org/LegalDictionary/D/DomesticAnimal.aspx):

> "Domestic animal shall include any equine or bovine animal, goat, sheep, swine, dog, cat, poultry, or other domesticated beast or bird."

While some people do initially think of pets when they hear the term "domesticated animal," (as do some [dictionaries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/domestic+animal)) the definition can expand beyond pets such as cats and dogs.

Comment: Thanks! But what would you think of if you heard someone say he or she worked in a 'Domestic Animal Food Production Company'? Would you be surprised if you later found out it was a livestock feed production firm?

Comment: *Domestic* and *domesticated* are not entirely the same.

Comment: @Tim: I'm no livestock breeder, or pet store owner, so I won't argue with you. But I will mention that [some dictionaries seem to blur the line](http://onelook.com/?w=domestic+animal&ls=a). To Mohammad: I wouldn't be shocked.

Answer (score 1):

"domestic' means animals that humans have had over the thousands of years, like dogs/cats. Cattle might be included but if unsure, it's better to refer to them as livestock to avoid confusion.

Comment: @MohammadSanei, Dogs and cats are not generally referred to as being "produced." To me, *Domestic Animal Production Company* means the company deals with livestock (such as cattle or hogs). Maybe your bigger concern is that your firm actually dealt with feed for livestock and not with the animals themselves??

Comment: @JLG Sorry that was 'Domestic Animal Food Production'. I just edited it. So you mean it's easily understandable? It's not problematic?

Comment: @MohammadSanei, "Domestic animal production" almost invariably refers to livestock production. Google it and see for yourself. It probably would have been more correct for the translation to be "Domestic Animal **Feed** Production Company" because you're talking about a company that makes the feed for livestock ... correct? As it is stated, it could be interpreted that the firm produced food out of domestic animals (like a packing plant), instead of making feed for livestock. This is probably a question you should ask the application office.